# opencv 3 python feature detection error on function cv2.detectAndCompute and also on cv2.compute

Tags: python, opencv

i use opencv 3.0.0 and python 2.7.5_x32

This is my code (ORB_feature_detection):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('C:\\Python27\\madar1.jpg',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('C:\\Python27\\madar2.jpg',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# line 12
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# create BFMatcher object

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10], flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is the error message, the error message is on the
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None) part,
i did work on opencv 2.4.11 and it doesn't work on opencv 3.0.0 !

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\orb_matcher.py", line 12, in <module>
   kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
error: ..\..\..\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:163: error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function NumpyAllocator::allocate
```

please help me, what should i do to make this work?

Comment: Same problem still occurs on Opencv 3.1, Python 2.7 x64 running Windows, worked fine back on Opencv 2.4 though. Therefore, the accepted solution as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33099160/2559632) doesn't work, at least not on Windows

Comment: Uncommenting the assertion and recompiling as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33877947/2559632) does the job though; so, who's gonna file the issue? :D

Comment: It would help to include the original images so that we can reproduce whether the issue is still there.

Answer (score 5):

You can try add this script after import cv2 and others `cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)` this solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you know why that line is necessary?

Comment: Because there are "a few problematic interactions between the python bindings and OpenCL" see more here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6081

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. You can find more information here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6081.

Today someone is fixing this issue: [T-API python support implemented #6847](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6847).